# Detect End of Video Playback in Web Page

Tags: javascript, video, html

Is there a widely supported video playback technology for web pages that provides an event/hook that can be captured from Javascript when playback reaches the end of the stream?

My goal is to provide a web page that plays a video and then asks the user a question about the video once playback is complete.  The question would be hidden or disabled until they have actually viewed the video.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

html5 video has an onended attribute

```
video.onended = function(e) {
  // do stuff
}
```

you can fallback to the JW flash player that has an [api](http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/Player5Events)

Comment: This would require the user to accept installation of the JW player, correct?

Comment: no, jwplayer is just a flash video player. you can download it for free and use it to play flv files as a backup to html5 video

Comment: Do you have (or can you point to) a well-tested HTML snippet that degrades well across many browsers from HTML5 to JW player (and ideally to a NOSCRIPT message)?

Comment: I have a div on my video player (HTML5) which shows up on Hover to show other video options (basically a playlist). I'd like a script that would show this div when a video ends, and disappear when one of the thumbnails is selected. How would I do this? This is the site: http://www3.carleton.ca/clubs/sissa/html5/

Answer (score 1):

I know that [JWPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/) can fire a Javascript event when playback has completed.

Source: http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/Player5Events